# How to use grocery set_relation function to display content from two different tables in different columns

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, datatable, grocery-crud

I have to tables with these schema:

```
users(id, name, email) 
user_details (id, user_id, physical_address, otherinfo)
```

I would like to display all contents of both tables in one grid using grocery crud
when i try to use set relation on the first table as shown: Note: I have reducted the part that does the rendering of the view;

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud->set_table('users');
$crud->set_relation('id', 'user_details', '{physical_address} + {otherinfo}');
```

the values of the id field as well as the referenced table don't appear in the grid, so it does not seem to work when using primary keys.

So I decided to start with the contents of the second table like so:

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud->set_table('user_details');
$crud->set_relation('user_id', 'users', '{name} + {email}');
```

This works, but the problem is that the values appear in one column in the grid. I would like to know how i can separate them to different columns and make them editable in separate input fields.

Answer (score 0):

my way kinda ridiculous,
if i were really need the field to be separated, i might use [callback_column](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_column) then use active records to return the value using `$row->user_id`, and callback each record

just like:
`return $this->some_model->get_name($row->user_id);` for name field
and
`return $this->some_model->get_name($row->user_id);` for email field

but, as i tested with some dummy records, it can't be sorted, (i dont know if anyone could)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to show multiple columns but i found an work around for this problem.
here is how
set name column as follows.

```
$crud->columns('name','email'); // define all required columns
$crud->callback_column(unique_field_name('user_id'),array($this,'callback_set_user_name'));

function unique_field_name($field_name) 
{
    return 's'.substr(md5($field_name),0,8); 
}

public function callback_set_user_name($value, $row)
    {
        $row->full_name = $row->s447d3092; // before getting to know s447d3092 key return json_encode($row); you will key pair with {name} + {email} ex: {"s447d3092":"shiva + shiv@gmail.com"}
        return explode("+",$value)[0]; // here you will have only name
    }

$crud->callback_column('email',array($this,'callback_set_email'));

public function callback_set_email($value, $row)
    {
      return explode("+",$row->full_name)[1];
    }
```

I am 100% sure this will help you